# The tables are not where I expect them

Tags: html, css

You can see in the first image where my tables are.

I tried to place them where I want using CSS but I couldn't do that.
I want them to look like the tables in the second picture.

I thought that my problem will be solved if I type in the tables some unclear sentences but when I did that, they didn't look like what I expected them.

What should I do?

[The first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaAbs.png)

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 6.250rem;
  background-color: #cbf1f5;
}

.mid {
text-align: center;
background-color: #cbf1f5;
}

.bottom {
background-color: #3fc1c9;
color: #11999E;
}
.footer-link{
  color: #11999E;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h2{

}
h3{
  color: #11999E;
}



.h1 {
  font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5.625rem;
  color: #11999E;
}

.firstP {
  text-align: center;
  color: #11999E;
}

.TopCloud {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15.625rem;
  top: 3.125rem;
}
.BottomCloud{
  position: absolute;
left: 15.000rem;
}
.mountain{
margin-left: 45rem;
}
h2{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h3{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
hr{
margin: 0rem;
}
.webdesign{

}
.webdev{
margin-right: 0rem;
}
table{
  border-spacing: 1rem;
}
.h3-webdesign{
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
}
.webdevT{
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 0rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Abdullatif Albahar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>



  <div class="top">
    <img class="TopCloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="Cloud">
    <h1 class="h1">Abdullatif Albahar</h1>
    <p class="firstP">A Web Developer</p>
    <img class="mountain" src="images/mountain.png" alt="">
      <img class="BottomCloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="Cloud">
    <br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<hr>
  <div class="mid">
    <div class="profile">

      <img  class="moon"src="images/real moon.png" alt="Me">
      <h2>Hi.</h2>
      <p>I am Abdullatif, a Web Designer/beginner Full Stack Web Developer & have a passion for web Development/Design.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="skills">
      <h2>My Skills.</h2>
      <div class="skill row">
        <table webdevT>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><h3>Web Development</h3></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quis, aenean amet.</p><p>Phasellus sodales, tellus donec dui, ornare erat.</p></td>
            <td><img class="webdev" src="images/web dev.png" alt="web development"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>



      </div>
      <div class="skill row 2">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><h3 class="h3-webdesign">Web Design</h3></td>
  </tr>
  <td><img class="webdesign" src="images/web design.png" alt="web design"></td>
<td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quis, aenean amet.</p> <p>Phasellus sodales, tellus donec dui, ornare erat.</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>


      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="contact me">
      <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non elit.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quis, aenean amet. Phasellus sodales, tellus donec dui, ornare erat.</p>
      <a class="email" href="mailto:albahar.abdullatif@icloud.com">Contact Me</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bottom">
    <!--make instagram & Twitter accounts for business-->
    <!-- add links -->
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Instagram</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Fiverr</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Freelancer</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Upwork</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Toptal</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Truelancer</a>
    <p>© 2020 Abdullatif Albahar.</p>
  </div>

</html>
```

[The second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unnpH.png)

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. Use CSS

Comment: As j08691 said, using tables for layout is discouraged. Use CSS Grid or CSS Flexbox instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the tables existing in the page to the center of the screen, you can add the following lines to your CSS file:

```
.skills {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I hope my answer will help you